# SSH asks password when invoke it in script

Tags: server, ssh

I have one master and four slave computers. I generated rsa public/private key on master PC. Then I copied publickey (`id_rsa.pub`) to slave machines as `authorized_keys`.

It doesn't ask password when I invoke SSH  like this on master PC's terminal:

```
ssh –o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null –o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@slave1
```

I wrote this script to automatically login slave machines without asking password.

```
SERVER_LIST=`cat /home/hduser/slaves` # slave1, slave2 ...
USERNAME=hduser
for host in $SERVER_LIST; do 
ssh –t –o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null –o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${USERNAME} ${host}; 
done
```

SSH is asking slaves passwords when I use this script. I'm getting this message when use SSH with `-vv` option:

[image: -vv option]

I changed permissions on master PC and slave PC.

```
sudo chmod 700 -R ~/.ssh
sudo chown hduser ~/.ssh
```

It still asking password. What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you forgetting the "hduser@" part in the script...?

Comment: It can ask me slave1's password without `hduser@`. I thought same thing and added it to script but nothing change.

Comment: Any special reason to Force pseudo-tty allocation(`-t`)?

Comment: Try to use add `-v` or `-vv` flag to ssh in the two cases, and compare the output --- maybe you can spot the problem that way.

Comment: I tried it (`-t option`) too but It didn't work.

Comment: see if any of [these answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/110814/184942) help.

Comment: I mean, try `ssh -v -o ...` from terminal (when it works), save the verbose output. Do the same for the `ssh ` in the script. Save it too. Normally this is sufficient to help you spot the problem, otherwise put the output in the question.

Comment: And also check that you have set the correct permissions, probably you need to have the same permissions for the key file and your script.

Comment: One more thing, use `@` to reply to users, otherwise we won't be notified.

Comment: your ssh is trying to login to root user (it is reading the /root/.ssh/ directory --- retry with hduser@$host in the script.

Comment: Thk you @Rmano . It works after copied `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` under `/home/hduser/.ssh/` directory to `/root/.ssh/` directory

Comment: So my first comment is the solution... you are still logging into the "slave" root account, not hduser, because you are calling the script from root (maybe with sudo?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `-i` argument.
From the man:

```
-i identity_file
         Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or
         DSA authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
         protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for pro-
         tocol version 2.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-
         host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have
         multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in config-
         uration files).
```

Then you can specify the key to use for each host.

Comment: `-i` option works too. I pointed hduser ssh directory and it works without copying private key to root ssh directory. I changed this line: `ssh –t –o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null –o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "/home/hduser/id_rsa" -l ${USERNAME} ${host};`

Answer (score 0):

The script somehow looks to root directory to send private key. It works after copied `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` under `/home/hduser/.ssh/` directory to `/root/.ssh/` directory.

```
sudo cp -av /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/
sudo cp -av /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/
```