# SSH public key added but still prompt for password

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've encountered an error when trying to setup so I can connect to my HTPC with my laptop, I've followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) guide from ubuntu help

This is my ~/.ssh/ permissions on my remote host

```
-rw------- 1 htpc htpc  398 Feb 29 15:16 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 htpc htpc 1675 Feb 29 15:15 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 htpc htpc  391 Feb 29 15:15 id_rsa.pub
```

this is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on remote host

```
# Authentication: 
LoginGraceTime 120 
PermitRootLogin without-password 
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes 
PubkeyAuthentication yes 
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When I try to enter from my local machine through SSH, it still ask me for a password even though my public ssh key is inside the authorized_keys on the remote host.

Debug log when connecting from local machine to htpc

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/mikeyr/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mikeyr/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mikeyr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mikeyr/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I've tried with my router as well and I have no issues getting it to work on that.

Comment: What are the permissions of `~/.ssh` directory? If they're not `rwx------` (700) or `r-x------` (500) and directory owner+group=user's (`htpc` here), then the authorized_keys file is also ignored. Next up: check that your local key from `/home/mikeyr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is listed in remote `.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: My /home/mikeyr/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is listed in /home/htpc/.ssh/authorized_keys  
Also I've just set the permission to chmod 700 on .ssh folder without any success of connecting without entering pw  
`drwx------  2 htpc htpc      4096 Feb 29 15:21 .ssh
`

Comment: Check also this list at U&L site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16978/how-to-make-password-less-login-work

Comment: Holy damn, that solution worked, 
I've tried to do `chmod 755` on all three directories `~`, `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` then restarted the service and now it works, thanks!

Comment: One last thing, since I don't know the protocol of askubuntu, should I let you post an answer providing the link so I can accept the answer? Or should I edit my post, telling that link fixed it or post the answer myself?

Comment: Interesting question. I'll turn my comments into an answer; I guess that would be best.

Comment: You can check the below answer, check if it works
https://askubuntu.com/a/1247116/925351

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains the line

```
 StrictModes yes
```

> Specifies whether sshd should check file modes and ownership of the
>   user's files and home directory before accepting login. This is
>   normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally leave their
>   directory or files world-writable. The default is ''yes''.

In other words, your home directory `~` on the remote host should be owned and group-owned by you (in this case, this probably means owner `htpc` and group `htpc`), and only writable by you (and potentially your group): that means no write in the last ("world") column

```
$ ls -la ~/
drwxr-xr-x 41 htpc htpc .
```

Note that the last part says `r-x` (not world writable), NOT `rwx`.

If there's a `rwx` in the last triplet, you need to remove the write rights:

```
chmod a-w ~
```

Similarly for the `~/.ssh` folder and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I would recommend `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` to only grant access to yourself for the folder, and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the file.

(Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16981/5477 for more server-side debugging tools)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to verify the destination server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to check where to copy the source public key (i.e. `authorized_keys` location in destination server)

In my case it was `/etc/ssh/keys/%u/authorized_keys2`

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/keys/%u/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
```

So try ssh password-less connection after copying your `authorized_keys` to corresponding location.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe while generating ssh-key you have added password to a key.

Generate new ssh-key `ssh-keygen`

`Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):` <- press enter as for default ( no password ).

Then `ssh-copy-id user@host`